# javascript passing a function that loops through array to a function that uses switch statement date method

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, date, switch-statement

I am trying to create a function that loops through an array and returns the results. I than am trying to pass this function to another function that uses a switch statement to check the dates of the values returned from the passed in function to display the day of the week ex sunday, wednesday etc to the console. All three values in the array are strings, with two of them being date values while the other is not.

I am obviously missing something as `myDate` function only returns one value, the first value from the array, also when it gets passed to the `findDate` function it does not return the expected results.

```
var myDate = function() {
  var input = ['10/11/2009', '11/10/2010', '-1'];

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var result = input[i];
    console.log(result);
      return result;

   }
};

console.log(myDate());

function findDay(myDate) {
    if (myDate !== -1) {
        var date = new Date(myDate), day = "";
        switch (date.toDateString().slice(0,3)) { //Pick the first 3 characters of a date string
            case "Sun":
                day = "Sunday";
                break;
            case "Mon":
                day = "Monday";
                break;
            case "Tue":
                day = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case "Wed":
                day = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case "Thu":
                day = "Thursday";
                break;
            case "Fri":
                day = "Friday";
                break;
            default:
                day = "Saturday";
                break;
        }
        console.log(day);
    }
    else{
        console.log(myDate + ' is not a valid date'); //If input is -1
    }
}

findDay(myDate);
```

Sample Input

```
10/11/2009
11/10/2010
-1
```

Sample Output

```
    Sunday
    Wednesday
    -1 is not a valid date
```

Comment: Considering the code you posted, what should `myDate()` should return?

Comment: Your `return` is inside the loop. Will always return during 1st iteration.

Comment: @leo.fcx myDate() should return the sample input in the array so when I pass it to the findDate() it checks each value through the switch statement

Comment: It does not make sense, why to iterate if you will return same array?

Comment: @leo.fcx one function purpose is to hold the values in the array and returns those values to be used in another function that determines the day of the week it is or not. If you have any solutions please feel free to suggest them even if it doesn't exactly fit this criteria

Comment: @SOSANA But, why do you need two arrays to do this? One array should be sufficient since you are not doing anything to change the values in the `input` array`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you might be right, just need a function myDate to callback the values and add it to findDate function, in this exercise I need to use a switch statement, but curious about other ways to solve this problem given the critiera

Answer (score 2):

If the myDate function is meant to apply some other function (findDay) to the list of inputs, it will need to look like this:

```
var myDate = function( callback) {
  var input = ['10/11/2009', '11/10/2010', '-1'];

// loop through list and apply callback to EACH item
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    callback(input[i]);
  }
};


function findDay(dateString) {
    if (dateString != -1) {
        var date = new Date(dateString), day = "";
        switch (date.toDateString().slice(0,3)) { //Pick the first 3 characters of a date string
            case "Sun":
                day = "Sunday";
                break;
            case "Mon":
                day = "Monday";
                break;
            case "Tue":
                day = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case "Wed":
                day = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case "Thu":
                day = "Thursday";
                break;
            case "Fri":
                day = "Friday";
                break;
            default:
                day = "Saturday";
                break;
        }
        console.log(day);
    }
    else{
        console.log(dateString + ' is not a valid date'); //If input is -1
    }
}

myDate(findDay);
```

Then you just need to modify findDay slightly so that it works on each date string that you give it.  Here is an example, if this is what you had in mind:

https://jsfiddle.net/2mnxcpwt/

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem, I needed to pass in a callback function and noticed from your jsfiddle the slight adjustment!, can you post your full  code in your answer rather than link to fiddle? for others in future?

Comment: I realized that in this solution you are passing findDay to myDate, myDate(findDay);when in Fact I need to pass myDate to findDay.....findDay(myDate)

Comment: findDay(myDate) invoked is suppose to be the solution. I thought myDate should be a function that iterates through an assigned array and when passed to findDay it would go through those returned values in the switch statement.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what myDate is supposed to do - is it just meant to return an array of Date strings?  If so, can't you just run findDay(myDate()), and then write find day to loop through the array?

Comment: yes thats correct, have solution now, but if you wanna update your solution I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is unclear. Usually you have a function which is a callback and some iterator for the array which calls the callback for every element. For example like this:

```js
var input = ['10/11/2009', '11/10/2010', '-1'],
    output = input.map(findDay); // iterator with callback

function findDay(myDate) { // callback
    var date, 
        days = { Sun: 'Sunday', Mon: 'Monday', Tue: 'Tuesday', Wed: 'Wednesday', Thu: 'Thursday', Fri: 'Friday', Sat: 'Saturday' };
    if (myDate !== '-1') { // <-- changed to string!
        date = new Date(myDate);
        return days[date.toDateString().slice(0, 3)];
    }
    return myDate + ' is not a valid date';
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(output, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: That's what I was missing, a callback, I like your answer, another way of solving this problem but I needed to use a switch statement :(

Comment: I up voted it due to having another way to solve this problem although it didn't quite fit the criteria I was given to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem was, that you checked if `if (myDate !== -1) {` and set for `myDate` in the array the value to `[..., '-1']`. So you wanted to compare a string with a number.

Additional to the problem above I have packed the task in one function:

```
function findmyDate ( input ) {
    input.forEach( function (myDate,k) {

    if (myDate !== '-1') {
        var date = new Date(myDate), day = "";
        switch (date.toDateString().slice(0,3)) { //Pick the first 3 characters of a date string
            case "Sun":
                day = "Sunday";
                break;
            case "Mon":
                day = "Monday";
                break;
            case "Tue":
                day = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case "Wed":
                day = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case "Thu":
                day = "Thursday";
                break;
            case "Fri":
                day = "Friday";
                break;
            default:
                day = "Saturday";
                break;
        }
        console.log(day);
    }
    else{
        console.log(myDate + ' is not a valid date'); //If input is -1
    }

  });
};

findmyDate( ['10/11/2009', '11/10/2010', '-1'] );
```

Test the function at https://jsfiddle.net/nrp24x0w/

Comment: I up voted it due to having another way to solve this problem although it didn't quite fit the criteria I was given to solve this problem

Comment: curious why you passed in additional argument k when its not being used?

Answer (score 0):

First, your array is:

```
 ['10/11/2009', '11/10/2010', '-1']
```

And, later you have:

```
 if (myDate !== -1)
```

Which will never be true since the array contains a string and you are checking for a number.

Next, inside your loop, you have:

```
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  var result = input[i];
  console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

There are two issues here:

1. The `return` statement is in the loop, causing the loop to terminate
   upon the first iteration.
2. Inside the loop, the old `result` value is being
   thrown out and the `result` variable is being reinitialized with the latest loop iteration value.

You should have:

```
var myDate = function() {
var input = ['10/11/2009', '11/10/2010', '-1'];
var result;

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  result += input[i];
}
console.log(result);
return result;
```

Now, you say "I am trying to create a function that loops through an array and returns the results." But, you haven't said how those results should be packaged. What do you want? A delimited list?  Another array?  Have you considered:

```
input.forEach(function(){ . . . });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Or:

```
var resultArray = input.map(function(){ . . . });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Since you seem to just want to check an array, it is not clear why you need a second array or a second function, but here's an example that does the main job:

```js
function checkArray(arr){
  
  arr.forEach(function(value, index, arr){
      if (value !== -1) {

        var d = new Date(value), day = "";

        switch (d.toDateString().slice(0,3)) { //Pick the first 3 characters of a date string
            case "Sun":
                day = "Sunday";
                break;
            case "Mon":
                day = "Monday";
                break;
            case "Tue":
                day = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case "Wed":
                day = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case "Thu":
                day = "Thursday";
                break;
            case "Fri":
                day = "Friday";
                break;
            default:
                day = "Saturday";
                break;
        }
        alert(day);
      }
      else{
        alert(myDate + ' is not a valid date'); //If input is -1
      }
  });
  
}

var input = ['10/11/2009', '11/10/2010', -1];
checkArray(input);
```

Comment: The results should be able to be passed to the findDate function where the switch statements go through each returned result logging the date or if its not a date

Comment: thank you for the clarification on your the two issues you mentioned but the rest of your comment didn't solve the issue

Comment: Your welcome. Feel free to up vote if this helped in any way.

Comment: I up voted it due to having another way to solve this problem although it didn't quite fit the criteria I was given to solve this problem

Comment: Thanks Scott , not just an answer but an explanation, its like giving a man a fish to eat for the day rather than teaching him to learn how to catch a fish and eat for the rest of his life :)

Comment: Scott, my intention is not to have two arrays, basically I need to pass myDate with array of given values to findDay function that iterates through a switch statement. The myDate can be anything, I just thought a function that iterates through the values and returns those values would be a better solution but I am open to all suggestions, technically myDate could be just a variable assigned to array, FindDay(myDate) could technically do the iterating and pass those values to the switch statement, not sure which one would be the better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing of strings by the Date constructor is strongly recommended against as it is largely implementation dependent and unreliable. The format "10/11/2009" is ambiguous, for some it's 11 October, for most it's 10 November. I'll guess you mean 11 October since that's a Sunday.

So you should never use the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are the same for parsing) to parse strings, a simple function to parse m/d/y format and validate the result is:

```
function parseMDY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[0], b[1]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[0]? d || new Date(NaN);
}
```

The result of *date.toString()* is entirely implementation dependent, there is nothing to ensure that the first three characters will be a day name so:

```
date.toDateString().slice(0,3)
```

might return anything. Far simpler is to use the built–in *getDay* method. If you **must** use a switch statement, then:

```
switch (date.getDay())
  case 0:
    day = "Sunday";
    break;
  case 1:
    day = "Monday";
    break;
  ...
```

but

```
var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday',
            'Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
var day = days[date.getDay()];
```

is much less to type.

Comment: any chance you could tie all the things you mentioned into a working example? I basically need to pass an array to findDay() using a switch statement. I thought having a myDate() function iterating through a array and passing those values as an argument to findDay(myDate) would be the solution but maybe its not. The problem I need to solve just states the expected example inputs and outputs